# How do I change the working directory while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) project in Visual Studio that reads configuration files from another project in the same solution. Once deployed, this application will run from the root folder for the solution, and the files will then be read from something like "<Executing assembly path>/Project1/connection.config".

When I however debug the Windows Forms application and get the executing assembly path, it will run from "bin/Debug" or "bin/Release", ergo the path to the configuration files is different.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio either debug the application from a different path or just copy the application once compiled and debug/run it from the same path as it will be run from once it is deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a post build event on your project to move the configuration file into the debug build directory.

Right click on the project that will require the configuration from a different project and select properties, click on the build events tab, and add a post build event. Something like this:

```
Copy configFilePath $(TargetPath)
```

Comment: Re *"...move the configuration file"*: Do you mean *"...copy the configuration file"*?

Answer (score 28):

In the project properties, open the debug tab. In there, you will find a textbox to change the working directory.

Comment: For some reason this still loads the executing assembly from bin/Debug

Comment: @Riri just change the Working directory

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by going to the project properties compile tab, and changing the build output path.  Hopefully this will work for you.

I believe you will need to change that back to bin\ when you are ready to do a release build.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, why it writes back to the same old folder may be administration rights.