# How to get the working directory?

Tags: c#, .net, path, directory

I'm using

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

to get the current directory I'm working in.

What I get is:

> "R:\AquaSafeWDS\FrontEnds\WPF\Clients\AquaSafe.Clients.LagrangeanSimulator\bin\Debug"

but what I really want is:

> "R:\AquaSafeWDS\FrontEnds\WPF\Clients\AquaSafe.Clients.LagrangeanSimulator"

Any ideas?
Rui Martins

Comment: What you are wanting is the project directory it would seem...but how does that help you in release code?  What is the goal?

Comment: @rui - please explain what are you trying to do. If you want to pass current source code path then please let us know your intention behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory - see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Well then this is the current working directory. After all this is where your EXE runs. The bin\Debug subfolder is how VS is laying out projects. If you need to have you EXE run in a different working directory, you may be able to instruct VS to do so. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102976/how-to-change-the-working-directory-while-debugging-in-visual-studio

Comment: Not a great solution - the working directory can change as you use the application, e.g., open file dialogs etc.

Comment: Well the question was how to get the current working directory. Whether or not this is a good solution to the OPs problem is hard to tell without knowing how the OP intends to use the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access files in your project directory (where your csproj file lives), which will be in the exe directory when you distribute your application and install it on another machine, then the best solution is to add the files to your project, and in the Properties window set them to copy to the output directory. The files will automatically be copied to e.g., bin\Debug when you build your project.

Now when you use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);`, it will give you the correct directory for your files.

Answer (score 1):

String DirectoryName = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
// It will get the name of the working directory

Answer (score 1):

This is not a practical problem.

But at application start if you want some directory to be your default working directory then in project properties you could select custom working directory -

[image]